# Adding arbitrary connections to my current channel in netty

Tags: java, jboss, netty

I have the following scenario for my project running on Netty:

- I have a server channel bound to 'w'
- I make a connection to a host using a local address 'x' to the remote address 'y'.
- I now need to allow messages coming from remote address 'z' to local address 'w' and put them in the same channel/channel pipeline as my 'x' to 'y' connection.

I basically need a bind('w', 'z') method for an existing channel, that will grab a connections from 'z' and include it in my existing pipeline instead of going to the server channel already bound at 'w'

Is this possible in Netty?

One (dirty) solution I can think of is to store these binding requests separately, and then when my server gets the respective connection it'll just create a 'forwarding' handler that will forward everything to my other channel.  Is there a simpler solution that's facilitated by Netty?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some kind of Proxy like service. Checkout the example [1].

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/proxy

Comment: The difference is that I need my local address to match the server bound address

Comment: I refined my question to a core issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475510/netty-initiating-new-connection-with-the-same-listening-address-as-a-bound-ser