# Netty - Initiating new connection with the same listening address as a bound server channel

Tags: jboss, netty

I have a bound server channel that is currently accepting connections at local address 'x'.  I now need to initiate a connection to a remote address 'y', but I need my local listening address to be 'x' as well.  When working with the local channel factory and local addresses, I get a 'address already bound' error when I try to make a new client connection with local address = 'x'.  This makes sense.

So my next route was trying to find a way to create a new child connection from the server channel, but this ended up going a little too deep into the netty internal code and seemed like a bad route to go.  I remember seeing a bug earlier about local client connections.

- Is this just a bug with local channels?
- Is initiating a connection from a bound address possible in Netty?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing a proxy?  If so, here's a netty [example app](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy).

Note that you have to setup different channel factories for client and server.

```
    // Configure the bootstrap.
    Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    ServerBootstrap sb = new ServerBootstrap(
            new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(executor));

    // Set up the event pipeline factory.
    ClientSocketChannelFactory cf =
            new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(executor);
```

Comment: No I'm not writing a proxy, my issue is that my local listening address for the new connection is the same as the bound listening address for the server channel.  That's not the case in the example.